# Quartz start at a specific time and run at specific interval

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I have been trying to come up with a cron expression to start a job at 8.30am and run every 30 mins until midnight and restart at 8.30am next day. I came up with following expression but only thing it lacks is starting at 8.30am. Rather than starting at 8.30 it starts at 8.00.

> 0 0/30 8/1 * * ?

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do? I'll be using java quartz2.x.x

Comment: @sYI3r This is possible if you refer this site **Cron Trigger Tutorial** [link](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html)

Comment: Hi @Kaviranga, if I'm going with  0 30/30 8/1 * * ? it simply won't run at 9.00 10.00 ... only way I can get it is 0 30/29 8/1 * * ? and let it at at 8.59 and 9.59. Do you have the solution to what I'm looking for?

Comment: @sYI3r If you are test this on a JSF web form open **quartz-config.xml** and include this line inside <trigger></trigger> tags **<cron-expression>0 0/30 8/1 * * ?</cron-expression>** . I've got this idea fron this site [link](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-quartz-2-example/).

Comment: @kaviranga With this expression it will start the trigger at 8.00am not 8.30am. That's the issue. It's quite interesting if no one has came across this issue before.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be not possible in single expression. There is good link, to create your cron expression, you may refer [Cron Maker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

**==Updated==**

You can have two cron expression

```
0 30/30 8 ? * * *   //every day 8:30
```

And,

```
0 0/30 9-23 * * ?  // every 30 min starts from 9:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the link @Ravi, yes I have been using this web site to see next schedule dates. And I can't seems to come up with a expression for this specific scenario.

Comment: Please check my update answer, let me know, if it is helpful.