# Configuring Cron Tasks every 10 minand start it at 6:30 am

Tags: linux, cron

How i can configuring cron task every 10 minutes from 6:30 am to 11 pm every day 
This is what I came out with: 
*/10 6-23 * * * my command.
but how i can start it from 6:30?

Comment: You can't, have to split it to at least two scripts.

Comment: Please, look here: It's similar question with response: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966927/quartz-start-at-a-specific-time-and-run-at-specific-interval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has said, you need two scripts.

First one : `*/10 7-23 * * *` > every 10 minutes from 7am to 11pm

Second one : `30,40,50 6 * * *` > once at 6:30 am,  6:40am, 6:50 am

Comment: Thanks for answer,  what about 6:40, 6:50? I need it ro run also at 6:40 and 6:50?

Comment: You said "every 10 minutes", so 6:30/40/50 should be run to. Doing this is done by 30,40,50